# Property '$auth' does not exist on type Promise

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I've just setup a new Nuxt.js app with Typescript and I can't solve some Typescript errors that seem to be related to the $auth module.
Here are the "types" settings in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
"types": [
  "@types/node",
  "@nuxt/types",
  "@types/nuxtjs__auth",
  "@nuxtjs/axios",
 ]
```

Here is the code:

```
      async login() {
        try {
          await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
            data: {
              user: {
                email: this.email,
                password: this.password
              }
            }
          })

          this.$router.push('/dashboard')
        } catch (e) {
          this.error = e.response.data.message
        }
      }
```

Here is the error:

```
Property '$auth' does not exist on type '{ login(): Promise<void>; }'.
```

I've found a few SO posts about adding the types to the `tsconfig.json`, which I did, but it didn't solve this issue.

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

nuxt.config.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
const axiosUrl = process.env.AXIOS_BASE_URL;
const port = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.PORT : 3333;

export default {
  // Disable server-side rendering (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode)
  ssr: true,

  // Global page headers (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head)
  head: {
    title: 'ollie-frontend',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css)
  css: [
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins)
  plugins: [
  ],

  // Auto import components (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components)
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended) (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules)
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/tailwindcss
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    '@nuxtjs/google-fonts',
    ['@nuxt/typescript-build', {
      typeCheck: true,
      ignoreNotFoundWarnings: true,
    }],
  ],

  // Modules (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules)
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth'
  ],

  // Build Configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build)
  build: {
  },

  server: {
    port: port,
  },

  axios: {
    baseURL: axiosUrl
  },

  auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/sign_in',
      logout: '/',
    },
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
          register: { url: '/signup', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: '/api/v1/users/me', method: 'get', propertyName: 'user' },
          logout: false
        }
      }
    }
  },

  router: {
    middleware: ['auth']
  },

  typescript: {
    typeCheck: {
      eslint: {
        files: './**/*.{ts,js,vue}'
      }
    }
  },
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "ESNext.AsyncIterable",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    },
    "types": [
      "@types/node",
      "@nuxt/types",
      "@types/nuxtjs__auth",
      "@nuxtjs/axios",
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: please share your `nuxt.config.js` file and `compilerOptions` in tsconfig

Comment: Are you using `export default Vue.extend({ ... })` or `export default { ... }` ?

Comment: no, the content of `nuxt.conf.js` and `tsconfig.js` files

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I've added it to the post

Comment: @NinoFiliu export default { } only, not Vue.extend

Comment: [The docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Basic-Usage) say that you have to use `Vue.extend` to get type safety

Comment: did you have `shims-vue.d.ts` in project root?

Comment: Hi All, I am getting the same error when using vue-3 with typescript. not using nuxt. do you know what to change in vue.config.js to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your default export:

> ```js
> export default {
>   ssr: true,
>
>   // ...
>
>   typescript: {
>     typeCheck: {
>       eslint: {
>         files: './**/*.{ts,js,vue}'
>       }
>     }
>   },
> };
> ```

Should actually be wrapped with `Vue.extend`, like so:

```js
export default Vue.extend({
  ssr: true,

  // ...

  typescript: {
    typeCheck: {
      eslint: {
        files: './**/*.{ts,js,vue}'
      }
    }
  },
});
```

This should result in TSC seeing the proper types when using the object now.

(By the way, the title is very misleading when compared to the actual TSC error that you had shown)